# Recharts inconsistency spacing in the Y Axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am trying to make the Y axis in rechart to space evenly up until the Y maximum. This value can change depending on the data that comes in.
My component is defined like this:

```
<YAxis allowDecimals={false} type="number" domain={[0, 'dataMax']} />
```

And this is the output:
[image]

Is there a way I can make rechart to increase by 5 consistently? For instance in this scenario spacing should go from 30 to 35 and then 38.

Answer (score 0):

Add properties `interval={0}` and  `tickCount={5}`  to the axis.

```
<YAxis allowDecimals={false} type="number" domain={[0, 'dataMax']} interval={0} tickCount={5} />
```

Comment: Almost there, but when dataMax is 44 it jumps from 20 to 38